# Regex for phone number starting with +

Tags: php, regex

With php `preg_match` , I found this regular expression for phone number code (such as +61)

```
$res = preg_match('/(\+\d{1,3})/', '+99999999'); // must return false
```

But it returns `true`. Maximum length must be 3. I mean (+999)

Any idea?

Comment: It matches for the same reason that `woman` matches `/man/` ;-)

Comment: @revo yashasin... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/761503)

Regex: `'/^(\+\d{1,3})$/`

Change regex: `/(\+\d{1,3})/` to `/^(\+\d{1,3})$/`

```
<?php
$res= preg_match('/^(\+\d{1,3})$/', '+99999999',$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it also returns false for `+99`

Comment: @vahidnajafi Please check, it is fine open this and check https://eval.in/761504